# Need SQL query to show the data in the below format

Tags: sql

I have columns like `id, name` as below

```
id name
1  A
1  B
1  C
1  D
1  E
1  F
2  A
2  B
2  C
```

I want to show data like

```
ID A B C D E F G
1  Y Y Y Y Y Y N
2  Y Y Y N N N N
```

Where :
     `Y` = *YES* - `EXISTS`
     `N` = *NO*- DOES `NOT EXIST`

Comment: What is your DBMS ? MySQL, Oracle, ... ?

Comment: I think you can't do it directly with sql.
Take a look at this example maybe it helps :
select 
 case MyFlag 
   when 1 then 'YES'
   when 0 then 'NO'
   else 'OOPS'
 end

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      id, 
      MAX( CASE when name = 'A' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) A,
      MAX( CASE when name = 'B' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) B,
      MAX( CASE when name = 'C' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) C,
      MAX( CASE when name = 'D' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) D,
      MAX( CASE when name = 'E' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) E,
      MAX( CASE when name = 'F' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) F,
      MAX( CASE when name = 'G' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ) G
   from
      yourTable yt
   group by id
```

Comment: @Sravan, you are welcome... also, as a newbie to the site, check out HELP -> TOUR for site eitquette